# git local repository is detached from my github account

Tags: windows, git, github

hopefully not TLDR
I have a source project on my local PC.  it was working fine, I could edit, add, commit, push;
I moved the local folders to a slightly shorter path (from d:\users\me\documents\github\crypto\intro\Exercise1.1 to d:\users\me\source\repos\crypto\intro\Exercise1.1)  no it is not connected to the remote https://github.com/masmowa/crypto;

here is what git remote says

```
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto> git remote -v                                                                     PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto> pushd .\intro\Exercise1.1\                                                        PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git remote -v                                                   IntroToCryptoEx https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (fetch)
IntroToCryptoEx https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (push)
introToCryptoEx origin (fetch)
introToCryptoEx origin (push)
origin  https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (push)
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch                                                      * master                                                                                                                PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch --al                                                 * master                                                                                                                PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch --all                                                * master                                                                                                                PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git help branch                                                 PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch -r                                                   PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch -r -v                                                PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1>
...
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos> code .\.gitattributes                                                                    PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos> pushd .\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1\                                                        PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git remote -v                                                   IntroToCryptoEx https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (fetch)
IntroToCryptoEx https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (push)
introToCryptoEx origin (fetch)
introToCryptoEx origin (push)
origin  https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx (push)
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git branch                                                      * master
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git status                                                      On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        AnalyzeCryptoMessage/AnalyzeCryptoMessage/Notes/wordsL4.csv
        AnalyzeCryptoMessage/AnalyzeCryptoMessage/Notes/wordsL4v2.csv
        AnalyzeCryptoMessage/AnalyzeCryptoMessage/Notes/wordsL5.csv
        AnalyzeCryptoMessage/AnalyzeCryptoMessage/output/DecryptMessage-output-20200316-164547-1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git push                                                        fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

PS D:\Users\Mark\Source\Repos\Crypto\intro\Exercise1.1> git push --set-upstream origin master                           remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx/' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Your remote URL is pointing to https://github.com/masmowa/crypto/IntroToCryptoEx, but all GitHub repositories have exactly two path components.  That means that your repository could be https://github.com/masmowa/crypto, or it could be elsewhere, but it isn't what you've specified.

To change the remote, you can write something like the following:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/masmowa/crypto
```

Note that if you're trying to push into the subdirectory of a repository, that won't work, since Git doesn't allow that.

Comment: Almost, I tried it but the root of the repository I am using seems to be in a subdirectory ./crypto/intro/Example1.1 I really want the history to point to ./crypto.  Also I somehow associated files and folders that are not subdirectories of ./crypto with the repository, and I am confused on how to remove these things from the repository and store them in a different repository that is more appropriate

Comment: It is simply not possible to push into a subdirectory.  You can find the root of the repository you're working in with `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.  If you want to create a new repository, you can copy part of your project out into a repository you've newly created with `git init`, and then push to a new remote.